# I want to set a default value for set_posting date if it's length is zero like 00-00-0000 in java

Tags: java

```
            pg.setPosting_date(Date.valueOf(str[15].length()==0 ? "0000-00-00" : str[15]));
```

I want to return date type object 00-00-0000 if the string length is 0

Comment: Checkout https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html

Comment: I recommend that you don't use `java.sql.Date`. That class is poorly designed, a true hack on top of the already poorly designed `java.util.Date`, and also long outdated. Use `LocalDate` from java.time, the modetn Java date and time API.

Comment: I recommend that in your SQL database you use `null` rather than 0000-00-00 for an absent posting date. This is what SQL nulls are for.  I am aware of the practice of using 0000-00-00, but I find it a poor practice.

Comment: You are asking the impossible. 0000-00-00 is not a valid date. `LocalDate` and `java.sql.Date` can hold only valid dates, not invalid ones as 0000-00-00.

Answer (score 0):

Set   ‘0000-00-00’ as sql column default value

```
ALTER TABLE Yourtablename

ALTER yourcolumnname SET DEFAULT ‘0000-00-00’
```

Now if the value is zero or the string length is zero means no need to set value in model. If date value null in the model means it’s automatically takes default value.

I hope it helps you thanks